# Compiler error when using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` of PHFetchResult

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I met the following compile error:

> Cannot invoke 'enumerateObjectsUsingBlock' with an argument list of
>   type '((_, _, _) -> Void)'

I think it may be easier to understand my situation with this screenshot of XCode6.3.

[image]

This codes is for testing the fetching of PHAsset objects using the `fetchAssetsWithMediaType` method. As you may know, this method returns PHFetchResult which has enumeration methods. I tried to enumerate all object in the result by `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`. Unfortunately, the Swift compiler gave me an error. After a long investigation, I ended up making a conclusion that this code is correct.

For your information, the above code is found by googling for testing PHAsset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question. a first parameter of a block of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is `AnyType!`. Therefore, `obj` argument for `append` method should be downcast with `as!`.

Anyway, I think an error message is not exact to point out this mistake. It seems that the compiler give this kind of an error message to a programmer when something wrong is in a block.

Comment: Yes, however it needs to be downcasted as `AnyObject!` not `AnyType!`